# Reading File content

Tags: c

Wrote a short program to read a file, and print the contents of the file on the screen. Below is a snippet of the code. It has an logical error. The program just compiles and prints nothing onto the screen. My thought process was read and print only the characters and skip over commas found.

```
    Eg file         
    A,1
    B,2

    Eg output
    A 1
    B 2

    char = str;
    while(fscanf(fpointer, "%c", &str) == 1)
    {
            while((str=getchar()) != ',')
                    printf("%c",str);
    }
```

Comment: "It has an logical error". It would make sense to tell us what incorrect behaviour you are observing, no?

Comment: Right. I updated the post. The program does not out put anything.

Comment: Did you read the man page to see what [`getchar`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) does? Having read that do you think it reads from where you want it to?

Comment: Maybe instead of ==1 substitute it with !=EOF

Comment: Reads a single character

Comment: I'm assuming from the user?

Comment: Code is incomplete.  Post more of code.  Tip: for debugging use `printf("%d\n",str);`

Comment: @mac But are you wanting that to come from `stdin`? No, right? You want to read the file. How do you think `getchar` will magically know which file you want it to read from?

Comment: Ok @Kaylum. So i'll pass fpointer into getchar as an argument. If i'm understanding you correctly. However, if that's thecase i did that and It did not work. getchar(fpointer)?

Comment: No don't just guess at what should be done. Read the man page. Does it say `getchar` takes any parameter? It should be obvious that `getchar` is not what you need. Another function is required. `fscanf` already reads a character. Why not just use its result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first while statement is correct. However, you don't use `getchar` in your second while statement. This will wait for the user to enter a character(this is why nothing is printing on screen for you). Try this method instead.

```
        while(fscanf(f, "%c", &str) == 1)
        {
                //while((str=getchar()) != ',')
            if( str==',')
            {
                        printf(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c",str);
            }
        }
```